# Google-TV device not found to pair with Google Anymote

Tags: google-tv

In building the Google Android app for Anymote tv control (I've got some Sony Google TVs to work with), I never actually seem to find the TV when I run it - just getting "No Google TV devices found on ".  I've tried it on an actual phone (not just the emulator) and have also tried the TV "connect" pairing button, but it never seems to find anything.  Both the phone and the TV are on the same WiFi network.  Anybody get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Does the google-tv-remote app work on your sony google tvs?  If so then I would check the source for that app, found [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-tv-remote/).  This should allow you to troubleshoot why your device is not found.  The process of discovering devices depends on mDns as found [here](https://developers.google.com/tv/remote/docs/index#discovery) in the docs.  So there are several things to check in regards to making sure multicast packets are allowed on your network/device.

As a fallback I would also allow manual ip entry in case a user wasn't able to discover the device on their network, the google-tv-remote allows for this as well, I would take a look at that source to get an idea of how that applications handles different scenarios.

And as always, if it's not working, provide some examples of how you are trying to do the discovery as you haven't provided any information(source, logs, etc) for anyone to look at.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with the sony google tv is that the multicast packets are reliably sent out shortly after the box is started. Paring at all other times is virtually impossible